# Facebook login message: "URL Blocked"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have problem

> URL blocked Failed to redirect because
> the final URI is not listed in the list of allowed URIs in the "Client" section
> configure OAuth "application. make sure login with OAuth
> enabled for client and web forms, and added all domains of your
> applications as valid OAuth redirect URIs.

error address
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=****&redirect_uri=https://*****/facebook_code&response_type=code&scope=email,public_profile

And my php code

```
public function facebookCodeAction() {
        return "
   
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : '{api-version}'
  });
    
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
    
};

(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = 'https//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>";}

   public function facebookLoginAction() {
    if (!empty($_GET->code)) {
      $params = array(
        'client_id' => ' my ID ',
        'client_secret' => ' SEC CODE',
        'redirect_uri' => $this->config['http_home_url'] . 'facebook_code',
        'code' => $_GET->code
      );

      $data = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params)));
      $data = json_decode($data, true);

      if (!empty($data['access_token'])) {
        $params = array(
          'access_token' => $data['access_token'],
          'fields'       => 'id,email,first_name,last_name,picture'
        );

        $info = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params)));
        $info = json_decode($info, true);

        if (!empty($info)) {
          $user = new UsersModule($this->dataBase);
          $token = new Token($this->config['key'], 'sha256', 'JWT');
          $user->load_user_data($info['email']);
          if ($user->getUser()) {
            $answer['token'] = $token->create_token([
              'id' => $user->getUser()->id,
              'name' => $user->getUser()->name . ' ' . $user->getUser()->surname,
              'src_photo' => $user->getUser()->src_photo,
              'group_id' => $user->getUser()->group_id
            ], 900);
            $answer['refresh_token'] = $token->create_token([
              'id' => $user->getUser()->id,
              'name' => $user->getUser()->name . ' ' . $user->getUser()->surname,
              'src_photo' => $user->getUser()->src_photo,
              'group_id' => $user->getUser()->group_id
            ]);
            $user->store_user_token($answer['refresh_token']);
            $answer['status'] = 'ready';
            if (isset($_POST->newItem) && !empty($_POST->newItem)) $this->newItem($_POST->newItem, $user->getUser()->id);
            return json_encode($answer);
          } else {
            $user_id = $user->create_new_user($info['first_name'], $info['last_name'], $info['last_name'], $info['email'], '00000000', 'notPass');
            $user->load_user($user_id);
            if ($user->getUser()) {
              $token = new Token($this->config['key'], 'sha256', 'JWT');
              $answer['token'] = $token->create_token([
                'id' => $user->getUser()->id,
                'name' => $user->getUser()->name . ' ' . $user->getUser()->surname,
                'src_photo' => $user->getUser()->src_photo,
                'group_id' => $user->getUser()->group_id
              ], 900);
              $answer['refresh_token'] = $token->create_token([
                'id' => $user->getUser()->id,
                'name' => $user->getUser()->name . ' ' . $user->getUser()->surname,
                'src_photo' => $user->getUser()->src_photo,
                'group_id' => $user->getUser()->group_id
              ]);
              $user->store_user_token($answer['refresh_token']);
              $answer['status'] = 'ready';
              return json_encode($answer);
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is an English-only site. You'll need to translate the error message (accurately) for us. Or you can ask at https://ru.stackoverflow.com instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not in English

Comment: Thanks for translating. The error message is telling you you have a configuration problem, not a code problem. You need to set the final URL correctly in your Facebook application settings

Comment: @ADyson 
The problem was there and there. I decided everything. Thanks !